# writing a text file on python

Tags: python, file, python-3.x

```
import time
def mainmenu ():
    print ("1.set values")
    print ("2. run formula")
    print ("3. export formula results")
    maininput = int(input("Enter: "))
    if maininput == 1:
        set_values ()
    elif maininput == 2:
        formula ()
    elif maininput == 3:
        export ()

def set_values ():
    set_values.first = int(input("Value 1 between 1 and 10"))
    while 1< set_values.first <10:
        set_values.second = int(input("Value 2 between 1 and 10"))
        while 1< set_values.second <10:
            mainmenu ()
    else:
        print ("That is not a valid value")
        return set_values ()

def formula ():
    part_1 = set_values.first + set_values.second
    print ("Value 1 + value 2 =",part_1)
    time.sleep(2)
    part_2 = part_1 * 5
    print ("Value 1 + value 2 x 5 =",part_2)
    time.sleep(2)
def export ():
    print ()

mainmenu ()
```

What code would I use in def export to replace print () so the data printed in formula is written to a text file.
Before the data is written the user should be asked to enter a file name and the code should check if a file with the same name exists and if so ask the user if it should be overwritten. If the user chooses not to overwrite the file they should be returned to the part where they enter the file name.

Comment: Google "python check if file exists" and "python write to file"

Comment: You should read the documentation before asking such a basic question. There are literally thousands (if not millions) of examples on the internet.

Comment: @BryanOakley I did check but there weren't any that matched my needs, I will check again through and if I find one ill delete this post.

Answer (score 1):

You should consult the documentation for `open` and `write` (link [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html)). Outside of that, the preferred method for writing to a file is the following:

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'w') as f:
   f.write('Writing to files is easy')
```

Comment: That is a copy of mine :(

Answer (score 0):

This is how to print to a txt file:

```
file = open("Exported.txt", "w")
file.write("Text to write to file")
file.close()
```

Another way to do so would to be:

```
with open('Exported.txt', 'w') as file:
   file.write("Text to write to file")
```

This is a program I made to write a txt file:

```
import os.path

def start():

    print("What do you want to do?")
    print("    Type a to write a file")
    print("    Type b to read a file")
    choice = input("            -")
    if choice == "a":
        create()
    elif choice == "b":
        read()
    else:
        print("Incorrect spelling of a or b\n\n")
        start()


def create():

    print()
    filename = input("What do you want the file to be called?\n")
    if os.path.isfile(filename):
        print("This file already exists")
        print("Are you sure you would like to overwrite?")
        overwrite = input("y or n")
        if overwrite == "y":
            print("File has been overwritten")
            write(filename)
        else:
            print("I will restart the program for you")
    elif not os.path.isfile(filename):
        print("The file has not yet been created")
        write(filename)
    else:
        print("Error")





def write(filename):
    print()
    print("What would you like the word to end writing to be?")
    keyword = input()
    print("What would you like in your file?")
    text = ""
    filename = open(filename, 'w')
    while text != keyword:
        filename.write(text)
        filename.write("\n")
        text = input()


def read():
    print()
    print("You are now in the reading area")
    filename = input("Please enter your file name:     -")
    if os.path.isfile(filename):
        filename = open(filename, 'r')
        print(filename.read())
    elif not os.path.isfile(filename):
        print("The file does not exist\n\n")
        start()
    else:
        print("Error")


start()
```

Comment: Directly comparing a return value  to a boolean value is never really a good idea. A better idea would be to simply use the truthiness of a boolean value. eg. `if boolean_return_value:`.

Comment: I'll take an example from your code. Change this `if os.path.isfile(filename) == True:` to this `if os.path.isfile(filename):`. Or another example, change this `elif os.path.isfile(filename) == False:` to this `elif not os.path.isfile(filename):`

Comment: So there is no need for the `== True` and `== False` because without the `== True` is the same thing, and you just add `not` instead of the `== False` at the end? (as in the not is added directly after the elif)

Comment: I have edited the answer, is that better? Is it now more Pythonic and clean?

Comment: I don't see the point in posting a program that is different from that in the question.

Comment: Also, is this answer good enough to be worth an upvote? If not, how can I improve it to be worth an upvote? @leaf

Comment: And @BryanOakley the program includes checking if the file exists and writing to the program, so the OP can see it implemented in working code

Comment: @RulerOfTheWorld I'm afraid not yet. What I pointed out to you was one improvement of your code. There are still some areas of improvement. Moreso, this question is poor, and very likely to be closed. So until the OP improves his/her question, I wouldn't speed energy trying to write an answer. Have a look around in the questions page, and see if there are any questions you like.

Comment: @leaf if the question was to be closed and you had upvoted, would I lose the reputation from that?

Comment: @RulerOfTheWorld No.

Comment: @leaf Thanks for your advice. I will continue to look for another question to answer that is written better :D